# Form isn't submitting data to my Model. How to create data on submit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Issue: Form isn't submitting data to Orders Table

I have a form_for that is connected to 2 controllers to  connect the data together once submitted.  I have recently connected Stripe Elements, which has its own controller.  I had a dummy form in place that when i submitted the info, the data would go through and save to the Orders Table.  I deleted the form and put the elements form in place, but the way i have it set up isn't submitting to the Table.

Here's the form:

```
  <form id="form-element" action="/charges" method="post" id="payment_form">


<%= form_for([@listing, @order]) do |form| %>


  <% if @order.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@order.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this order from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% order.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <script

    src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/">
    // data-key="pk_test_3vX123456789YKE1f0B8"
    // data-amount = {@listing.price}
    // data-locale="auto">

  </script>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="card-element">
        Credit or debit card
      </label>
      <div id="card-element" class="form-control">
        <!-- a Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
      </div>

      <!-- Used to display form errors -->
      <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
    </div>
      <br>
      <div class="form-group">

    <%= form.submit "asdf", class:"ripple-effect", id:"button-element" %>
  </div>

  <span class="token"></span>
  </form>
  <% end %>
  </div>
  <script>

   ....
</script>
```

In my OrdersController, here's my create method:

```
def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:listing_id])
    @seller = @listing.user

    @order.listing_id = @listing.id
    @order.buyer_id = current_user.id
    @order.seller_id = @seller.id
    ....
```

Here's my ChargesController:

```
def create

    @amount = 500
    token = params[:stripeToken]
    payment_form = params[:payment_form]


    charge = Stripe::Charge.create({

      :source  => 'tok_visa',


      :amount      => @amount,
      :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
      :currency    => 'usd'
    })

  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to new_charge_path
  end
```

I tried throwing in orderscontroller info to the chargescontroller, and vice versa.  Wouldn't work. then figured it's just the way the form is set up.  So basically, if that's the solution, how can i make it so when i input the form, the data registers to the orders table.

This information may help so.. here's the dummy form that would successfully forward the information to the order table: https://pastebin.com/th2WC8Lj

I added form.submit to the stripe form, but that didn't do it.  I figured it would at least create a blank order.

attempt at using ajax to asynchronously submit forms.. not working.

```
<script>
...
  $('#Orders').on('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/charges",
          data: $('#payment_form').serialize()
      }).then(this.submit.bind(this));
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

At present, the form is posting to the `charges` endpoint which means only the `ChargesController#create` code is being called. You need to do the following:

- Duplicate the charge creation code into the `OrdersController#create` method and remove the `<form id="form-element" action="/charges" method="post" id="payment_form">` tag at the top of your code block. That will then submit the form to the `OrdersController#create` method.

The reason I say duplicate the code is because we don't know if charges can be created without an associated order, in which case you'd want to retain the ability to create charges independently.

Comment: The issue with this is the stripe form is dependent on Javascript... I did try it though, nothing happened on submit for either the order or stripe token.  http://jsfiddle.net/k4j05Lu6/ - in what way can i set up the form to be combined so on submit both are entered one after another?

Comment: Can you post a Gist of the generated HTML form code in your Rails app please? That'll help me determine why nothing happened when you submitted the form.

Comment: the form looks like the above in the OP, but with an added "    <%= form.label :name %> or 2.. but the thing is, without the <form .. > you're saying to remove, it won't work, to my knowledge, because it is connected to the javascript which then sends the API request to stripe.  somehow we need to combine them.  I have fiddled with ways to asynchronously submit the forms with javascript AJAX but haven't nailed it yet.
ill post above my attempt above.  i'm trying a few other methods.  i believe this needs to be done with javascript AJAX to work.  let me know if you have any thoughts or ideas.

Comment: You can modify the example Javascript Stripe has provided to create the token and submit the Rails-generated form in a way that will create the order _and_ charge the payment source. :-)

To be super explicit, you do not _require_ the original <form> tag for this to work with Stripe Elements.